# Android Studio - Run and install the app with lower API

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I usually use 3 emulator to test the apps (JB, KK and Lollipop). But now I am using my Surface Pro and I can't use a lot of emulator. Then I only use my real nexus 5 device but it is a problem because I am using code for v21 and v19, and I can't test v19.

Is it possible to install the app forcing the v19 in my Nexus 5 with Lollipop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no.
the nexus 5 with Lollipop is a Nexus 5 with Lollipop (API level 21).

your choices are:

- struggle with the emulator on a slower computer
- buy another device for testing
- buy/use a faster computer
- flash the factory image of KitKat on the nexus 5 from here: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images (not great option in my opinion)

Comment: Okay, thank you for the info. Google should implement the option to forcing to use the level api that we want...

Comment: As Suhai mention on the other answer, for sure, Genymotion is somewhat a better emulator, but still, if you're on a slow computer it will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution would be that when creating a new emulator, you can select `x86` in the `ABI` column which would use Intel HAXM to run the emulator faster.

Comment: Just 4 gb ram... Chrome + Android Studio take all

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GENY MOTION` ,It is faster then your emulator and its free for personal use.

You can find it there https://www.genymotion.com

Comment: Thank you, I used it in my desktop PC, but really that I want is not possibe to do.